# How do I add values I got from forEach? (reactjs)

Tags: json, reactjs, foreach

I'm trying to extract data from an API call that gives me this JSON:

JSON data:

```
{ "rows": 
    [
        {
            "customer_id": 1,
            "customer_details":
                {
                    "customer_id": 1,
                    "email":"john@mail.com",
                    "first_name":"John",
                    "last_name":"Doe",
                    "phone":"+123456123"
                },
            "order_items":[
                {
                    "name": "random name",
                    "quantity":1
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "customer_id": 2,
            "customer_details":
                {
                    "customer_id": 2,
                    "email":"johnny@mail.com",
                    "first_name":"Johnny",
                    "last_name":"Silverhand",
                    "phone":"+123456123"
                },
            "order_items":[
                {
                    "name": "random name",
                    "quantity":1
                },
                {
                    "name": "another random name",
                    "quantity":1
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am actually able to get the the quantity but when there are two or more objects from the array in `order_items` like with customer 2, what I get is `11` how do I add the values I get? Sorry if this is really a simple problem but I am really confused.

here is my code for how I get them:

```
    function getQuantity(qty) {
        if(qty.length === 1) {
            return qty[0].quantity;
        } else {
            let tempArr = [];
            qty.forEach(prod => {
                // console.log(prod.quantity)
                tempArr.push(prod.quantity)
            });
            return tempArr;
        }
    }
```

I mapped used the function I made inside a map here is part of the code:

```
{orderList.map((val, key) => {
                                    if (val.status_id !== 5) {
                                        return (
                                            <tr key={key} className='text-center'>
                                                <td className='tdata'>{getQuantity(val.order_items)}</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getQuantity` function returns an array of numbers (given this json data) and when you set the value of your `td` to be, as in your example, `[1, 1]` it will output "1""1" which will look like "11".

If you want to display the sum of your values, you could do something like this (although there is probably a better way to sum all the numbers in an array)

```
   function getQuantity(qty) {
        if(qty.length === 1) {
            return qty[0].quantity;
        } else {
            let tempVal = 0;
            qty.forEach(prod => {
                tempVal += prod.quantity
            });
            return tempVal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: don't know why I didn't think of this lol, I was making it more complicated in my head.  Thank you for this!